# most reliable format for large bigquery load jobs

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a 100 GB table that I'm trying to load into google bigquery. It is stored as a single 100GB avro file on GCS.

Currently my `bq load` job is failing with an unhelpful error message:

```
UDF worker timed out during execution.; Unexpected abort triggered for
worker avro-worker-156907: request_timeout
```

I'm thinking of trying a different format. I understand that bigquery supports several formats (AVRO, JSON, CSV, Parquet, etc) and that in principle one can load large datasets in any of these formats.

However, I was wondering whether anyone here might have experience with which of these formats is most reliable / least prone to quirks in practice when loading into bigquery?

Comment: Please clarify--by "100 GB table" do you mean that you have a single 100 GB Avro file? It may work better to load smaller files, e.g. each 1 GB in size, although BIgQuery does parallelize reading from large Avro files.

Comment: Yes I have a single avro file at 100 GB. Clarified in original question.

Comment: Is it an option broke this huge file in a ton of small files ?

Comment: @hkanjih Yes I'm trying this now. I'm surprised that the documentation didn't mention this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'll solve following these steps:

1. Creating a ton of small files in **csv** format
2. Sending the files to **GCS** .

Command to copy files to GCS:

```
gsutil -m cp <local folder>/* gs:<bucket name>
```

> **gsutil -m option** to perform a parallel
>   (multi-threaded/multi-processing)

After that, I'll move from **GCS** to **BQ** using **Cloud Dataflow default template**. [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#gcstexttobigquery). (Remember that using a default template you don't need code)

Here a example to invoke dataflow [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#gcstexttobigquery) :

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME \
    --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_BigQuery \
    --parameters \
javascriptTextTransformFunctionName=YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION,\
JSONPath=PATH_TO_BIGQUERY_SCHEMA_JSON,\
javascriptTextTransformGcsPath=PATH_TO_JAVASCRIPT_UDF_FILE,\
inputFilePattern=PATH_TO_YOUR_TEXT_DATA,\
outputTable=BIGQUERY_TABLE,\
bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory=PATH_TO_TEMP_DIR_ON_GCS
```

Comment: Hmm why use a dataflow job when a simple `bq load` would suffice?

Comment: Time to process, I guess that process more than 100 GB using a single process BQ Load I'll take a long time. But probably it will work :-)

Comment: Bigquery Load jobs from GCS are executed in parallel, so I also don't understand why the dataflow job is necessary.